# Need help identifying a component

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, identification

I'm trying to identify a specific component on a circuit board here (circled in red on the photo, and highlighted in red as "Q1" in the circuit).  Note that the four diodes, one capacitor, and the voltage regulator are all lumped together as "DC 5v" in the circuit diagram, while the three 470 ohm resistors on the right are lumped together as R3:

[image: PCB photograph]

[image: Circuit diagram]

For context, I should probably describe the function of the circuit.  When voltage is first applied to the circuit, LED D1 is lit.  However, when S1 is closed momentarily, D1 is turned off and stays off until S1 is pressed again (at which point it turns on, rinse and repeat).

Obviously, without any identifying markings, it's impossible to identify the component Q1 is exactly, but I just need some initial direction so that I can choose a component of similar function and value.

Comment: A flip-flop ic might make sense here.

Comment: It's switching power, it's an IC, and it's an SOT-5 package, so there are some search terms to start with. Not sure if I should post an answer as this question may be bordering on being off topic.

Comment: @evildemonic It's almost certainly a dedicated power switch IC,.

Comment: @winny Why would a switch need an inductor?

Comment: Sorry, I read switcher, as in DC-DC.

Comment: Here's something like what I'm talking about, but not the exact IC, There are a lot of this type of thing out there to search through. https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max16054.pdf

Comment: Are there any markings on the IC?

Comment: @rdtsc None at all.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the P/N is rubbed off by Mfg, so I am wondering why you need this info. Pls Advise.

The momentary switch triggers a toggle function, normally done by Qbar to D and clk input pulse.

I found an SOT-23 with such a device but it is not compatible and needs a jumper from Qbar to and pullup R on CLK.  So keep looking or ask a better question.

[image]

Then I looked closer to see your unreadable photo to see a SOT23-6 not the  -5 in your schematic.

The correct pin#'s are CCW from pin 1 not alternating sides for these chips.

But this still does not match since the power is on the center pins. So keep looking.

[image]

---

### REV A

Your questions needs more clarity/accuracy to find a match to verify Vcc and Gnd pins. Yet the answer given by @Tarabas seems close but not quite the same.

[image]

Neither does a single D FF IC below fit exactly , but can be made to work with Qbar to D input jumper and CLK in.  (CLR# to V+)

[image]

Comment: It's definitley SOT23-5.  There is no physical pin at the "right middle" position, nor is there a solder pad.

Comment: There is also no physical connection between the "left middle" lead and anything else on the board.  It's just an open lead.  Trust me, I spent more than half an hour trying to figure that out.

Comment: As for the pin numbers, I just used what Visio assigned in my quick and dirty drawing, which was only meant to illustrate the component in question.

As for the photo being unreadable, what do you mean?

Comment: If you see a physical lead then show it on logic schematic with no connection.  The photo says it has 6 leads which is important info to match part, but is unreadable for surface reflection of numbers which is also important info.  The convention for pin numbers, now you know, is left to right and  CCW top view from dot for pin 1. Connectors may have different rules than IC's.

Comment: Alright. I thought I was as clear as I could possibly be in the logic schematic.  So I'll try to be clearer here.  Counterclockwise from top left pin:
-
Pin 1 (a1 on my schematic): 5V supply (you can call this Vcc if you want)
Pin 2 (a2 on my schematic): No connection
Pin 3 (a3 on my schematic): Ground
Pin 4 (b3 on my schematic): This lead shorts to ground when the circuit is to be turned off
Pin 6 (b1 on my schematic): "input" lead.

Comment: There is no physical "pin 5", nor is there a pad on the circuit board.  The mark you are indicating as "2 cut???" appears to be a silkscreen print mark and has no metalic/conductive properties.  The trace underneath it passes from the capacitors on the left of the picture, to pin 1 (a1 on my logic schematic), underneath the mystery component, to one of the resistors on the right.  It is the 5v supply line.

Comment: The logical schematic I offered was to illustrate the exact physical location of each of the traces in question.  there is no "cut" to any traces on the board.

Comment: OK see what I mean about photo quality. yes 5 pin but a trace goes under it probably to Pin 2 on datasheet and looking almost like https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJWNh.png

Comment: Tony:  As stated previously, the trace passes underneath the component to pin 1 (upper right).  It's the 5v supply, or Vcc.

I'm sorry I couldn't get a better quality photo, that cropped photo is the best I could manage off my iPhone.  The others were worse.

Comment: I am wondering why you need this info. Pls Advise.

Comment: I thought of telling you it wasn't any of your business, but I( wanted to avoid antagonizing you since you have put in a good effort to help me.  I have three reasons:  1), when this circuit fails, it's often this component that goes up in smoke.  I have 4 dead examples, and I am trying to figure out why.  2)  To learn about them  3) To experiment with utilizing such a device in my own circuit

Comment: Thank you. This is important to know if you want accurate answers.  Flyback voltages from dry contact disconnection on the positive side, will then produce negative voltage and may damage to any chip here.  A series diode can block that.  But more info is still needed.

Comment: When I started working in the 70's my musician buddy had a blown synth with 30 CMOS IC's and all the p/n's sanded off.  it took me 2 hrs to fix it. So if you want it fixed, give more details.

Comment: WHat details do you want?  The failures usually occur the first time the circuit is powered on.  If it doesn't occur then, it almost never occurs.  It also ONLY occurs when power is applied to the circuit, not when cycling on/off using the momentary switch (in this case, a magnetic reed switch).  So picture this:  You have two three identical boards, all fresh out of the box.  You apply power to all three (14v).  All three light up, but one starts smoking, from this component.  It smokes for a while then goes dark.  The other two are fine.

Comment: Some more details about the function of this component:

when power is first applied to the VCC (pin 1, upper left), the resistance between pin 4 (lower right) and pin 3 (pin 3 is GND, bottom left) is extremely high, about 25 Mohms.  When pin 5 (upper right) is shorted to ground (pressing button/activating reed switch), pin 4 to pin 3 resistance drops to 25 ohms.  As one other user surmised, this pulls the base voltage for Q2 down and deactivates that transistor, turning off the LEDs.

Comment: Pin 2 (middle left) has no discernible function.  It is not the "opposite state" of Pin 4 (lower right), nor is is connected to any other pins on this component, or any other components on the board.

Comment: I should also mention, that using the switch repetitively, toggles on and off the light.  I have searched through latches and flip flops on Digikey, but all of the ones I have found, the outputs are positive voltage, not a (relative) short to ground.

Comment: No, They are complementary so they pull both high and low.  I also showed one with dual outputs Q, Q#

Comment: One final note, is that the state of the circuit stays in whatever state it was switched to when the switch is "unpressed" so if you press the switch, the light will turn off until the next time you press the switch, at which point it will turn on and stay on until the next time you press it, etc).  This is what lead me to assume it was some sort of flip flop or latch.

Comment: Yes 1 T or D FF as I showed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141253/discussion-between-trainboy-and-tony-stewart-ee75).

Answer (score 0):

This could well be a On/Off controller with debounce, something like to MAX16054 for instance, but with just one of the outputs. I'll assume it has an inverted output that is pulled down after the first button press, and lowers the base voltage enough to switch off the transistor.

See the datasheet for inspiration: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAX16054.pdf

It would help a bit to have the size of the package, to know if it is of size SOT23-5 or SC70-5. It might not be relevant here, but would improve your question to have the resistor values in your reverse engineering schematic ;-)

Comment: SOT23-5  R1 is 4.7k, while R2 is 220 ohms.  R3 is not relevant.